# how to re size the image which is saved in sql database with var binary format using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imgData = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter {
  ParameterName = "@photo",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary,
    Size = imgData.Length,
    Value = imgData
});
```

I've been using this code for storing images. I've stored some images in SQL database in Var binary format with 256 x 256 size. And now i'm trying to display those images in grid view , its working fine , but the problem is ,its taking too much space of grid view and its looks very ugly.

So i wanna re size that images into 48 X 48 and then i want to display.

So please tell me how to re size the var binary format image before displaying in grid view Using C#

Comment: Format your question..

Comment: Can you share the code how you display this images in grid. Then we can provide a solution.

Comment: dont post code in comments.rather use edit question and add the relevent details.